# Font files (.ttf, .woff) are inaccessible in React Native Webview

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

Accessing the font files from my CSS using relative paths returns a 500 error for me from my React Native Webview. I have no issue on this using my webapp and I run the file in the browser (http://192.168.1.5:19000/assets/dart/assets/fonts/flaticon.woff), the browser automatically downloads the file. Do I need to configure anything else on my WebView?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadHTMLContent = async () => {
    try {
      let assetsUri = Asset.fromModule(require('../../assets/dart/index.html')).uri;
      assetsUri = assetsUri.replace('/assets', '');
      const baseUri = assetsUri.split('/index.html')[0];
      setBaseUrl(baseUri);
      fetch(assetsUri).then(response => response.text()).then((content) => {
        setHtml(content);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  loadHTMLContent();
}, []);

<WebView
  ref={webViewRef}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={{ html, baseUrl }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
  scalesPageToFit={true}
  scrollEnabled={true}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  onLoad={handleLoad}
  onMessage={handleMessage}
  allowFileAccess={true}
  allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
/>
```

Then inside my index.html

`<link href="/assets/dart/css/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I can view this file from the browser too, this is how it's referenced in the css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("/assets/dart/assets/fonts/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("/assets/dart/assets/fonts/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/assets/dart/assets/fonts/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/assets/dart/assets/fonts/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://tgldcdp.tg.org.au/assets/css/extlib/fonts/flaticon.svg") format("svg"); /*important get a copy*/
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Can anyone point out why I'm getting error 500 when CSS is trying to access .woff and .ttf files?

Answer (score 0):

you have to load the font and create a `file:///' url, see here

```
const loadFonts = async () => {
    try {
      let asset = Asset.fromModule(
        require("../assets/gfont.ttf")
      );
      await asset.downloadAsync();
      let fontUri = asset.localUri;
      asset = Asset.fromModule(Fonts[fontName]);
      await asset.downloadAsync();

      let css = `
      @font-face {
      font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url("${fontUri}") format('woff2');
      }
      
      @font-face {
      font-family: '${fontName}';
      src: url("${asset.localUri}") format('truetype')
      }

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}`;
      return css;
      postMessage("font", css);
    } catch (e) {
      return "";
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
```